# receive file from simple form to ActionResult

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to receive a file from vie, by using simple form
here it is what I've tried

VIEW

```
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "_CreateStudent";
}

<div class="CreatePartial">
<h2 class="blue-color">Create Student</h2>
<form method="POST" action="@Url.Action("Create","Student")" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div>
        <label for="Key">Student ID</label>
        <input type="text" name="StudentID" hidden id="Key" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="FirstName">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="FirstName" id="FirstName" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="LastName">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="LastName" id="LastName" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="Photo">Profile Picture</label>
        <input type="file" name="PhotoURL" id="photo" />
    </div>

    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

CONTROLLER

```
        //CREATE STUDENTS POST
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(StudentModel student, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (file != null)
        {
            file.SaveAs(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Images/") + file.FileName);
        }

        var StudentData = new Student()
        {
            StudentID = student.StudentID,
            FirstName = student.FirstName,
            LastName = student.LastName,
            PhotoURL = file.FileName
        };

        db.Students.Add(StudentData);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

MODEL

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApplication3.Models
{
    public class StudentModel
    {
        [Required]
        public int StudentID { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter FirstName to Proceed")]
        public String FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter LastName to Proceed")]
        public String LastName { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Select your Profile picture")]
        public String PhotoURL { get; set; }

        public List<StudentModel> _StudentList { get; set; }
    }
}
```

but i'm getting `HttpPostedFileBase` `null`

but the `StudentModel` is received `FirstName`,`LastName`, `PhotoURL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You post your input like this:

```
<input type="file" name="PhotoURL" id="photo" />
```

Controller doesn't map your file becouse input name attribute that doesn't correspond your model or controller.

If you set name attribute `PhotoURL` you either should write your Controller signature like this:

```
public ActionResult Create(StudentModel student, HttpPostedFileBase PhotoURL)
```

Or extend your `StudentModel` with `HttpPostedFileBase` property:

```
public HttpPostedFileBase PhotoURL { get; set; }
```